# How to combine RichMarker within angular-google-maps directive

Tags: google-maps, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Does anyone knows how to combine RichMarker within angular-google-maps directive?

Best regards,
Chen

Comment: Having same problem. Directive wont work anyway.

Comment: Isn't the idea with RichMarker that you can just use it in place of the built in Marker for google? http://jsfiddle.net/PS64e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [ng-map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps), because of some philosophical difference.

This is very easy with ng-map. It looks like this

```
  var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngMap"]);

  app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(evt, map) {
      new RichMarker({
        map: map,   // !! $scope.map
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.80, -74.13),
        draggable: true,
        flat: true,
        anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
        content: '<img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3212/3012579547_097e27ced9_m.jpg"/>'
      });  
    });
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XOY25pFzd8OnzloPvACn?p=preview

For more about ngmap, visit http://ngmap.github.io

Answer (score 0):

1. make rich marker library a angular module. and name the factory RichMarker
2. Create a directive and pass the element with information to show to this directive. Also pass RichMarker factory here. simply create the marker.

Comment: Can you please provide an example not very clear for me.